Login in google page with requests or Oauthlib
Good day, I have a task to fill out and submit data on this site: Click Quality Form using Python code, and I encountered the following issues:
I cannot find which Google API corresponds to this site (if any);
And when trying to parse this site, it asks me to log in.
I tried logging in through google_auth_oauthlib but it still doesn't let me access the form. Perhaps I'm not specifying the right scopes, or not passing the necessary headers in the request. Maybe someone has already dealt with such a task and knows how to properly implement the authorization to get access to this site. The only thing I managed to do was to send a request with __Secure-1PSID, __Secure-1PSIDTS in the cookies, but for me, this is not a solution since I took these cookies manually from the browser, and I didn't find another way to obtain them.
I am very hopeful for your help, thank you in advance!
Trying to login with google_auth_oauthlib:
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

# client-google.json is Credentials from google console
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client-google.json',
    scopes=[
        'openid', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    ]
)

credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'})

url = 'https://support.google.com/google-ads/contact/click_quality'
response = session.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_content = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    file_path = "google_ads_click_quality.html"
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(soup.prettify())
else:
    print("status code:", response.status_code)

in google_ads_click_quality.html i have google login page
